# How can I solve for a variable in an equation?

Tags: python, sympy

I have this equation:

```
x(t) = V*t + (V^2/A)*exp^(-(A/V)*t) -(V^2/A)
```

In my equation `x(t) = 40`, `A = 5.378572`and `V = 14.608438`. I would like to solve for t. How can I do this with sympy in Python without rearranging my equation and putting it in terms of `t`?

Comment: This sound more like a math than a programming question.

Comment: I mean I can solve it interms of t using wolfram alpha but the issue is when you open it out you get a massive equation for t. However, I feel like this can be done programmatically. Sympy in Python allows you to solve equations but it doesnt allow you to isolate variables. I'm not sure about this though. Thats why I posted. To see if anyone knows how to solve for t without having to rearrange the equation and putting it interms of t before feeding it into sympy.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sympy, you could use [`nsolve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve) as follows:

```py
from sympy import Eq, exp, nsolve
from sympy.abc import t

x = 40
A = 5.378572
V = 14.608438
print(nsolve(Eq(x, V*t + (V**2/A)*exp(-(A/V)*t) -(V**2/A)), t, 1))
```

Result: `5.02757996605981`

Alternatively, the symbolic equation could be solved:

```py
from sympy import Eq, exp, solve
from sympy.abc import t, x, A, V

print(solve(Eq(x, V*t + (V**2/A) * exp(-(A/V)*t) - (V**2/A)), t))
```

Result: `[x/V + V*LambertW(-exp(-A*x/V**2 - 1))/A + V/A]`

Where [`LambertW`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) could be [called as a regular function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#lambertw) to find specific values.